# strftime timezone gives word form instead of offset

Tags: perl, posix

I'm trying to get the current time in perl using strftime, but it doesn't give me the time zone in the form I want. According to this: http://search.cpan.org/~dexter/POSIX-strftime-GNU-0.02/lib/POSIX/strftime/GNU.pm, %z is used for the form "-0700", and I saw some where else that %:z gives form "-07:00" which would be ideal.

But %z is giving me the timezone name, and %:z doesn't even work.

```
    use POSIX qw/strftime/;

    #This prints "2014-09-30T12:54:11-Pacific Daylight Time"
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%z\n", localtime(time)); 

    #This doesn't print anything
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%:z\n", localtime(time));

    #What I want: "2014-09-30T12:54:11-07:00"
```

Comment: What does `man 3 strftime` say for `%z` on your system? Or rather, what does it say you need to use? This is the function you are using.

Comment: You're not using `POSIX::strftime::GNU`, so why are you quoting its documentation?

Answer (score 1):

POSIX::strftime uses your operating system's underlying `strftime` library. So the options available to you are listed in your local manpages. As the [POSIX documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) says:

> Consult your system's strftime() manpage for details about these and
>   the other arguments.

That's probably "man strftime".

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I get the expected results.

```
$ perl -MPOSIX=strftime -E'say strftime("%z", localtime)'
+0100
```

You need to look closer at your local implementation of `strftime`.